# TF204000: The Team Foundation server to which your team project is connected does not support the Rollback command

Tags: tfs, rollback

When I try to rollback my bad changeset using `tf rollback /changeset:xx` I'm getting next error:

> TF204000: The Team Foundation server to which your team project is connected does not support the Rollback command.

Is it possible to fix that someway? [Googling brings not result](http://www.google.com/search?q=TF204000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are using TFS 2010 on the back-end?  It sounds like you might be using Visual Studio 2010 against TFS 2008.  If that's the case, try installing the [TFS Power Tools October 2008 release](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fbd14eea-781f-45a1-8c46-9f6ba2f68bf0&DisplayLang=en) and rollback using that.