# Rollback Changeset - VS2010 / TFS2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, rollback

I'm trying to rollback a changeset, and I'm not getting it.
I'm using `Visual Studio 2010`, but the `Team Foundation Server is 2005`.

I've tried to do with Power Tool 2010, but it didn't work. I already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210547/tf204000-the-team-foundation-server-to-which-your-team-project-is-connected-doe), but I think that Power Tools release 2008 won't help too, but I gonna try anyway.

If you know some way to do rollback with `VS2010 and TFS2005`, please tell me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to rollback ..? are you trying to move .aspx pages that were coded in 2005 converted to 2010 back to 2005..??? how come you did not make a backup copy before converting or changing..?? can you get at a previous version from TFS when doing a checkout..???

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm trying rollback a changeset and I wanna get back to the previous changeset of each files. I read on the internet that I need the right PowerTool to do it, but when I installed PowerTools 2010 release 2011 the rollback didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Power Tools isn't working then consider this:

If you are dealing with a small amount of files/changes then you can do a "Get Specific Version" on the files and choose the version/date/changeset you want to "roll back" to.  Once you have that version of the file(s) locally then just check it back in as if it were an edit.  Essentially you have rolled back your change.

Comment: Matt, it was a small number of files, so I did this manually like you said. I thought about making this before I open this question, but I found out that TFS2010 had a rollback option and I tried to do using it, but in the server where the files are doesn't support the rollback command. Thanks.

Comment: I work with TFS 2010 and "get specific version" is still definitely the way to go. The rollback command that comes with the power tools has nevr worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TFS 2005 then you need the 2005 verion of the [power tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/11/16/493401.aspx) to do a rollback

You'll probably find a few quirks trying to use the 2010 version of Team Explorer with the older versions of TFS, particularly with the command line tools so its probably a good idea to have Team Explorer 2005 installed even if you're not using VS 2005 to develop your code.

On a side note TFS 2010 is significantly nicer to use than 2005, upgrade ASAP!

Comment: James, thanks for the help. I think the TFS 2010 is nicer too, but the company where I work doesn't want to upgrade. I'd to rollback a changeset manually, cause neither the TFS 2008 works here.